# Save spatial reference to application settings?

Tags: arcobjects, .net

Having created a tool as a macro for several geoprocessing tasks, I'm saving user input to application settings so the user doesn't have to enter all required data on each use.  I'm stuck on saving the spatial reference.

ESRI code shows using the FactoryCode and an enumeration to create either a projected or a geometry spatial reference.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the enumeration, and how to identify whether the factorycode/enumeration points to a projected or geometry spatial reference.

Comment: That should be handled by the environment settings.

Comment: I'm weak on the programming side, so I don't feel I can treat this as an answer. You can use the factorycode (aka well-known ID/WKID) directly. You don't need the enumeration/macro. You can't directly check the factorycode. You would have to check the coordinate system object itself using TypeOf, for instance. You can also store the well-known text (WKT). This doesn't store the rest of the spatial reference info (min xy, resolution, and tolerance values).

Comment: In the Settings.settings file, create a record to store your custom object and make it any type (string, int). Then open the Settigns.Designer.cs file, find the statement for the record you just made and change the type to whatever object type you wish, including any user-defined type referenced in you project. The setting can now be referenced and updated programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

In the Settings.settings file, create a record to store your custom object and make it any type (string, int). Then open the Settigns.Designer.cs file, find the statement for the record you just made and change the type to whatever object type you wish, including any user-defined type referenced in you project. The setting can now be referenced and updated programmatically.